# correct indexPath.row selection in TableView which has multiple sections?

Tags: iphone

i am having tableview with multiple sections .each section is having different no of rows.
when i select in particular row in particular section, how can i find correct indexPath.row
?any tutorial?

Answer (score 15):

I don't know what you mean by "correct". The `indexPath.row` is always local to the section, which means

```
section 0
---------
[ row 0 ]
[ row 1 ]
[ row 2 ]
---------    
section 1
---------
[ row 0 ]
[ row 1 ]
---------
section 2
---------
[ row 0 ]
[ row 1 ]
[ row 2 ]
[ row 3 ]
---------
```

To get the global row, you can compute a partial sum.

```
NSUInteger row = 0;
NSUInteger sect = indexPath.section;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sect; ++ i)
   row += [dataSource tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
row += indexPath.row;
return row;
```

Comment: yes ..u r right but for example section 2 (row 1) represents over all 
ROW 6,how can i get it?

Answer (score 1):

UITableview sends the delegate a

`willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and
`didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message

and it send a

`UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification` notifications to observers.

By listening to these messages your will know what rows are selected.

There is a template in xCode with a UITableView which is a good starting point for learning UITableView. Your could implement it around an NSArray of strings as your datasource. That way focusing your learning effort on the UITableView code.

Best way is really to make a simple UITableView and flesh out the delegate methods along with the any calls to observers step by step.

Apples class reference will get you a long way.