# TableView IndexPath.row not Assignable

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview

I would like to assign tableView indexPath to one of the view controller variable. However, it is strange to me that it assigns one of them, no matter which row I choose, it always assigns 0.
As you can see below code, iVC.virdsection=indexPath.row works very well, but sVC2.evradID=indexPath.row always 0.

```
//
//  TableViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "SubViewController.h"

@interface TableeViewController : UITableViewController
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSArray *contentArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic)DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@property (strong,nonatomic)SubViewController *subViewController;
@end

//
//  TableViewController.m

#import "TableViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"
#import "SubViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@end

@implementation TableViewController
@synthesize contentArray;
@synthesize detailViewController;
@synthesize subViewController;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    DetailViewController *iVC = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.detailViewController = iVC;

    iVC.virdSection = indexPath.row;
    iVC.navigationItem.title=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.Vird",indexPath.row+1];

   SubViewController *sVC2 = [[SubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.subViewController = sVC2;
    sVC2.evradID=indexPath.row;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:iVC animated:YES];
}


Here is my SubViewController.h
//  SubViewController.h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *evradLabel;
-(void)evradCall;
@property int evradID;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The row 0 is the first row. If you log `indexPath.row` it will probably show all the indexes of the rows. 0 is technically correct. Try this code

```
NSUInteger row = 0;
NSUInteger sect = indexPath.section;
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < sect; ++ i){
sVC2.evradID = i;
}
```

(I found this [here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107603/correct-indexpath-row-selection-in-tableview-which-has-multiple-sections)

Comment: Hello Chris, that is not my problem

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, but I've had it happen to me before, is `sVC2` nil?  You could have a problem instantiating sVC2.

It's kind of hard to tell what's going on from code posted.

Comment: How do you test whether or not sVC2 is nill? I also put subviewController.evradID, but it is still 0.

Comment: You could do `NSLog(@"%@", sVC2);` and see what comes out.  Properties on nil objects will return 0.

Comment: Are you thinking it's wrong because the value is zero? If so, are you aware that index path is both a row and a section? The first row in every section is numbered "row 0". Thus, if your table is divided into multiple sections then the first row of each is number 0. Hard to tell how your table is set up.

Comment: Hello Bill, I just want to assign indexPath.row to my variable sVC2.evradID.